# How to paginate affected files in a commit using GitHub API?

Tags: github, commit, github-api

When getting the files affected by a commit, I noticed that there is a limit in the files array, which lists only the first 301 files.

For instance, the following commit has more than 6 thousand affected files, but only the first 301 are listed in the files json array:

https://api.github.com/repos/aleberringer/loja350/commits/e9c301b1e5a2cfed9bf05e9f9429ae81ad0d1ebd

How can I get all the affected files of this commit? I tried to paginate using &per_page and &page parameters, but it didn't work out.

Comment: From the API docs: "Note that for technical reasons not all endpoints respect the ?per_page parameter, see events for example." It looks like pagination isn't supported for that endpoint.